# EXIF python PIL return empty dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, exif

I can't figure out why _getexif() returns an empty dictionary. I know that the image contains EXIF data as shown by ImageMagic :

```
>> identify -verbose image.jpg

Properties:
    date:create: 2015-01-12T16:20:26-05:00
    date:modify: 2013-07-01T14:05:08-04:00
    exif:ColorSpace: 1
    ...

exif:Model: PC800 PROFESSIONAL
    exif:ResolutionUnit: 2
    exif:SceneCaptureType: 0
    exif:WhiteBalance: 1
    exif:XResolution: 72/1
    exif:YCbCrPositioning: 2
    exif:YResolution: 72/1
    jpeg:colorspace: 2
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 2x1,1x1,1x1
    signature: e63fcbacdfd031e611b83befaa4a9c8ef6235894da10784a692f90832205ec60
  Profiles:
    Profile-exif: 931 bytes
```

Now try to read EXIF with python2

```
img = Image.open('image.jpg')
>>> img
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image.jpg mode=RGB size=2048x1536 at 0x7FEDF2E8A518>
exif = img._getexif()
>>> exif
```

returns nothing...

I also tried with pyexiv2, same result:

```
>>> import pyexiv2
>>> metadata = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata(img)
>>> metadata.read()
>>> metadata.exif_keys
[]
```

Any ideas why I can't read theses exif data into python ?
Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 24 2014, 18:26:21) on Arch Linux.

Comment: PIL works fine for me. What do you get using the example image form here http://www.exiv2.org/sample.html

Comment: Works fine on this image example with PIL. So Python can't read my images metadata, but ImageMagic can. Any known issues with Python and Reconyx camera metadata ?

Comment: I guess I could try to read the metadata from python with an imagemagick call ?

Comment: yes that would be simple, FWIW I tried an example image from the reconyx  website and I also got None back

Comment: `from subprocess import check_output c = check_output("identify -verbose img.jpg".split())
print(c)`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was fearing this... Do you think it could cause portability issues to use imagemagick from python ?

Comment: No prob, you're welcome.

Comment: this should create a dict with all the relevant info http://pastebin.com/hwcXYfpX

Comment: That does it. Thanks ! Could you post it as an answer ?

Comment: No prob, I added an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative  to using `_getexif()` we can use [subprocess.chck_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to run `identify` and parse the output into a dict:

```
from subprocess import check_output

c = check_output("identify -verbose img.jpg".split())
d = {}
print(c)
for line in c.splitlines()[:-1]:
    spl = line.split(":",1)
    k, v = spl
    d[k.lstrip()] = v.strip()
print(d)

{'Blue': '', 'Border color': 'srgb(223,223,223)', 'Compression': 'JPEG', 'Elapsed time': '0:01.000', 'Artifacts': '', 'Overall': '', 'blue primary': '(0.15,0.06)', 'Dispose': 'Undefined', 'jpeg': 'sampling-factor: 2x2,1x1,1x1', 'red primary': '(0.64,0.33)', 'Interlace': 'JPEG', 'Compose': 'Over', 'Tainted': 'False', 'Filesize': '3.9KB', 'Pixels per second': '0B', 'Units': 'Undefined', 'Chromaticity': '', 'Number pixels': '7.5K', 'Type': 'TrueColor', 'Red': '', 'Channel depth': '', 'blue': '8-bit', 'Background color': 'white', 'Transparent color': 'black', 'verbose': 'true', 'min': '0 (0)', 'Resolution': '72x72', 'Image statistics': '', 'filename': 'img.jpg', 'green primary': '(0.3,0.6)', 'Print size': '1.38889x1.04167', 'Channel statistics': '', 'Class': 'DirectClass', 'red': '8-bit', 'Matte color': 'grey74', 'Page geometry': '100x75+0+0', 'skewness': '-0.284137', 'Geometry': '100x75+0+0', 'max': '255 (1)', 'Colorspace': 'sRGB', 'Depth': '8-bit', 'Green': '', 'date': 'modify: 2015-01-13T19:18:06+00:00', 'User time': '0.000u', 'Rendering intent': 'Perceptual', 'kurtosis': '0.369947', 'Gamma': '0.454545', 'Orientation': 'Undefined', 'Endianess': 'Undefined', 'Image': 'img.jpg', 'Format': 'JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)', 'white point': '(0.3127,0.329)', 'Properties': '', 'green': '8-bit', 'Iterations': '0', 'signature': '620e0541b826edb6dc5a2420beaaf697fdf6682ba50f915b8ab767fafbb3b7d2', 'standard deviation': '46.9874 (0.184264)', 'Quality': '85', 'mean': '133.602 (0.52393)'}
```

If you don't want keys with empty values use `if v` before adding the key/value

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work for me. It return a lot of errors with the last line: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application. Do you know what might be the problem?